# Facebook integration not working in different devices

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am building an app where I am trying to integrate facebook. When I am using device of android 2.3.3 its working fine and i am able to post message. But when I am running that same app in android 4.1 then it showing "failed to post".I am using facebook-sdk version 3.6.0

My code as below

FacebookActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.facebook);

        btnPostStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnPostStatus);
        edtPost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_text);

        edtPost.setText(messageToPost);

        btnPostStatus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                restoreCredentials(facebook);
                messageToPost = edtPost.getText().toString();
                if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                    loginAndPostToWall();
                } else {
                    postToWall(messageToPost);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
        Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
        editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
        return editor.commit();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
        facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
        return facebook.isSessionValid();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void loginAndPostToWall() {
        facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
                new LoginDialogListener());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void postToWall(String message) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", message);
        parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
        try {
            facebook.request("me");
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("")
                    || response.equals("false")) {
                showToast("Blank response.");
            } else {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            saveCredentials(facebook);
            if (messageToPost != null) {
                postToWall(messageToPost);
            }
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        }

        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        }

        public void onCancel() {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

It not showing any exception, but not able post

Is there any good fb integration tutorial which using latest facebook sdk version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved my problem. When I am setting a target-sdk version in my manifest.xml then its working for lower version android device but its not working for my jelly bean android device.
So when I remove target-sdk version then its working properly in jelly bean device also .